# Изменение состояния объектов GUI JavaFX не из основного потока JavaFX

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Доброе время суток.

Есть у меня небольшая проблема, связанная с многопоточностью в `JavaFX`. Если быть точнее, у меня есть некоторая таблица, которая формируется через получение состояния объекта с сервера. Если какое-то поле изменилось, нужно обновить его в этой таблице, изменить отображение (цвет, размер текста и т.п.) и, возможно, выкинуть информирующий диалог. Так как таких объектов может быть несколько, я использовал TabPane, а на нём на каждой вкладке `GridPane` (собственно, сама таблица), для каждой вкладки свой поток, который опрашивает сервер и сравнивает полученные значения с имеющимися. `GridPane` состоит из объектов типа `Label`, у которых я и пытаюсь изменить состояние.

Выбрасывается `Not on FX application thread`

Искал решения, но ничего путного не нашёл, ибо мне надо опрашивать сервер каждые `n` секунд. Использование `Platform.runLater(Thread)` не подходит, так как мне надо опросить сервер, уснуть на `n` секунд, и опросить снова, а если я попробую уснуть, то моё приложение тоже засыпает вместе с этим потоком.

Вот сам поток, который я запускаю на каждой вкладке:

```
public class Seeker extends Thread {
private User userBefore;
private Label[] labelsBefore;
private Label[] labelsNow;

public Seeker(User userToSeek, Label[] labelsBefore, Label[] labelsNow) {
    userBefore = userToSeek;
    this.labelsBefore = labelsBefore;
    this.labelsNow = labelsNow;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        TimeHelper.sleep(1000);
        User userNow = APIHolder.getUserAPI().getInfo(userBefore.getHandle()).getResult().get(0);
        if (!userBefore.equalsAllFields(userNow)) {
            List<String> fieldNames = ReflectionHelper.getFieldNames(User.class);
            List<String> userFieldValuesBefore = ReflectionHelper.getFieldValues(fieldNames, userBefore);
            List<String> userFieldValuesNow = ReflectionHelper.getFieldValues(fieldNames, userNow);

            for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.size(); i++) {
                String valueBefore = userFieldValuesBefore.get(i);
                String valueNow = userFieldValuesNow.get(i);
                if (!valueBefore.equals(valueNow)) {
                    if (isTime(fieldNames.get(i))) {
                        labelsNow[i].setText(getTimeFromMillis(valueNow));
                    } else {
                        labelsNow[i].setText(valueNow);
                    }

                    labelsBefore[i].setTextFill(Color.DARKRED);
                    labelsBefore[i].setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.BOLD, 15));

                    labelsNow[i].setTextFill(Color.DARKGREEN);
                    labelsNow[i].setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.BOLD, 15));
                }
            }

            userBefore = userNow;
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как можно это реализовать.

Comment: Как обычно. Вычисляйте всё в фоновом потоке, а обновляйте UI в UI-потоке. Как именно перебросить задание в UI-поток наверняка есть в документации.

Comment: А можно поподробнее, пожалуйста? А то я не представляю, как это сделать

Comment: Если верить гуглу, вам нужно [`Platform.runLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: А что я в runLater буду закидывать? Мой Seeker? Так тогда у меня уснёт моё приложение на веки вечные.

Comment: В `runLater` вы закидываете только ту часть, которая обновляет UI. Все вычисления остаются в фоновом потоке. При этом, разумеется, вам придётся разделить код на части: первая часть собирает нужные данные, вторая обновляет UI (у вас почему-то всё вперемешку).

Answer (score 1):

В JavaFX нельзя изменять состояние объекта UI не в UI потоке. Используйте паттерн [Observer](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) для уведомления UI об изменении модели.